# How to prevent apps from being restored after reboot?

Tags: windows-10, reboot

Using Windows 10 LTSB (Build 17763.1098).

Say I have Google Chrome running and click *Start → Power → Restart*. The PC shuts down and restarts as expected. After log in, the deskop is displayed... and then after ~5 seconds Chrome automatically restarts! Why? Same thing if Task Manager was running when I restart. After reboot, Task Manager is automatically restarted.

What controls this and how can I ask Windows to show the desktop only after a reboot?

Comment: Hello, I've tried to clarify the title a bit and clean up the formatting. If you don't like the changes, feel free to [revert them](https://superuser.com/posts/1546141/revisions).

Comment: Err, I'm not sure those edits are improvements! As a first language English-speaker, "restore" means something different from "restart". Not sure why you prefer Task Manager to `Task Manager`...making it stand out a little helps to focus on the important point that application `XYZ` restarts when I didn't want it too. Will think about and come back later, but thanks for the input.

Comment: @AlainD - Your question should have never been edited. The edits add absolutely nothing, however, your question is indeed a duplicate of an existing question

Comment: @Ramhound: Yes, the edits aren't really that helpful. The linked question is indeed a duplicate and has resolved my issue. Thanks.

Comment: @AlainD - As the author of the question you can reject any edit to your question.  If a community user continues to suggest an edit, you would want to raise a moderator flag, instead of rolling back their edits.  In this case I suggest just allowing the edit stand, since your question is a duplicate, and the edit didn't change all that much.  UWP applications are indeed **restored** not **restarted** to the same state after a reboot.

Comment: @Ramhound: Yes, no need to revert the changes now. Curious use of **restore**. To me this would imply the program is returned to the exact same state as before which is not quite what happens. For example, if you were editing a Word document on page 15, the application would be **restarted** on page 1...but not **restored** to page 15. Thanks again...

Comment: @AlainD - Word returning to the same page is a feature of Word.  Windows opening or restoring your user instance, applications must also support it, is a feature of Windows 10 (specific versions)